# How to add headers when we DUMP the data in output file using PIG scripts?

Tags: apache-pig

I tried to search for it but cannot find the tip/recommendations.
Here is my situation. I have all the data lined up correctly and output working fine using pig script. Stored the files in a output directory. The output files are more than 100 files so what i have done is accumulated the results file using another pig script.

I was wondering if there is anything in PIG LATIN that will help me add "Header" to the accumulated results file so that business users can quickly use it as it also has headers?

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DUMP in Pig script and redirecting the result to a single file, you can use DESCRIBE before DUMP. Doing so will append schema information as header to your output file

```
A = LOAD 'test' USING PigStorage() AS (col1:int, col2:chararray);
DESCRIBE A;
DUMP A;
```

output will be something like:

```
A: {col1: int,col2: chararray}
1,test
2,test
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pig can store the schema into a different file ".pig_schema" using PigStorage:

store A into 'outputFile' using PigStorage('\t', '-schema');

will save your data in the outputFile using tabs as delimiters and also creates the schema file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the header in a separate file, `LOAD` it and `UNION` it with your data. Then you need to do an `ORDER BY` (that might be tricky depending on your data).

Another way would be to use hadoop getmerge.

In general, this is not something pig is very good at, you might as well write a script in another language.